# integral of a function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

I wanted to find the integral of the function $f(x)$ from zero to one: $$f(x)=\begin{cases}2x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x) & : x\in(0,1]\\ 0 & :x=0\end{cases}$$

but I think whether its integral is not defined or is $\sin 1$.
please help me with this question.

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Integrate by parts

Comment: @GrahamKemp In this situation, I would rather guess than integrate by parts.

Answer (score 3):

The function is bounded and continuous on $[0,1]$ except $x=0$, so it is Riemann integrable. A simple calculation shows that $F(x)=x^2\sin \frac{1}{x}$ is a primitive function of $f(x)$. Hence, the integral is $F(1)-F(0^+) = \sin1$.

Comment: It might be better to say the integral is $F(1)-\lim_{x \to 0^+}F(x)=\sin(1)$

Comment: Could you please explain what is the limit of the $f(x)$ at the point zero or it is indefinite ?

Comment: It is indefinite.